# Invalid token 'void' when compling async..await on build server

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am currently writing a class that uses the async..await-Pattern to do asynchronous tasks.
In it I have a method like so:

```
public async void DoSomething() {
  ...
  await SomeObject.DoYourThingAsync();
  ...
}
```

For the reference: The project is set to use .NET-Framework 4.5 and I am using VS2012.
On my machine it compiles and works just fine, but when I check it into TFS, the build generates an error in the declaration of the function.
The message is: Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Try change `void` to `Task`.

Comment: Your build server does not understand the `async` modifier, so when it reaches the `async` keyword it presumes it's a name of a type, and expects the following token to be a name of a field, property or a method (and it throws an error because it gets a reserved word `void`).

Comment: Did you have installed in the build server .Net Framework 4.5 ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your build server does not understand C#5 syntax. For a C# 4 compiler `async void` (or `async Task` for that matter) looks like you have specified two return types.

Reconfigure the build on the server to use C# 5 syntax or a newer version of the compiler.